# Create pre-defined select box with information from Database

Tags: php, sql

I have two arrays both are coming from my SQL server

Example:
Array 1 (45, 46, 47, 48)
Array 2 (46, 47)

My code is as follows:

```
<select>
   <?
      while($array1 = $t->fetch_object()) /*Get from DB*/ {
        foreach($array2 as $a2){
   ?>
       <option <?=$array1 == $a2 ? 'value="'.$array1'" select="selected"' : 'value="'.$array1.'"'?>><?=$array1?><option>
<? } }?>
</select>
```

This will produce itself multiple times as it loops array2 twice. I for some reason can't figure out how to run this properly without the multiple options. (Maybe I have been working all day) But any help will definitely be appreciated.

EDIT:  so instead of the output being:

45 
46 selected
47 selected
48
45 selected
46 selected
47
48

It be:
45
46 selected
47 selected
48

The above loops through twice due to the foreach and I'm not sure how to have it just loop through once. Hmm maybe if I have $i = 1 and it stop at the next count.

To clarify I am using this http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ dropdown menu.

Comment: im not clear as to what you actully want to happpen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might don't understand well your question, but what I see from the code. You are trying to make default selection from array2. My way to do this would be :

```
<select>
<?php
//Here comes the php

//Variables
//---------------
$array2 = array(46,47);
//---------------

//Looping into the fecthed data
//------------------
while($array1 = $t->fetch_object()) /*Get from DB*/ {
    //Initalization of looping variables
    $boolFound = false;
    $i = 0;

    //looking into aray2 for default values
    while($boolFound == false && $i < count($array2)) //While a default is not a match 
    {                                                 //or the end of array2
        if($array2[$i] == $array1) //Is this a default value?
        {
             $boolFound = true; //Yes, we stop the loop
        }
        else
        {
            $i++; //No, we continu until the end of array2
        }
    }

    //Either we have a default or not we output the option
    echo('<option value="'.$array1.'" ');

    //if it is a default, we output "selected"
    if($boolFound)
    {
        echo('select="selected"');  
    }

    //Then the value itself, and we close the html
    echo('>'.$array1.'</option>');
}
//------END of data looping------------
//END of PHP    
?> 
</select>
```

The problem with this. You may have more than 1 "default" option (selected).

Hope this help.

antoine

(also I am a little rusty in php, not sure about "$array1 = $t->fetch_object()" part.)

Comment: Actually just switched some variables around and it worked on my end. Thanks! Also the ->fetch_object is right after I did a selection in MySQL.